# What javascript event is tied to "waiting for localhost"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wait until the "waiting for localhost" message in the browser goes away before running some function.

Is it

```
$(document).ready(#myfunction) 
or
 $(window).load( #myfunction );
```

or is it something else?

Comment: We don't know what event your browser's message is referring to, so it's hard to answer. `.ready()` signifies that the entire DOM (the HTML structure of the document) has been loaded. `.load()` fires when the DOM, plus all external resources have been loaded. In your case, it's likely the latter.

Comment: That means the browser is trying to download the page - it hasn't even received your javascript yet - but there would be very little point running JS that soon as there's no document for it to modify. The soonest you can run Javascript is to put it in the `<head>` and not include it in any jQuery function - it will be exeuted as soon as it's read by the browser

Comment: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: window.onload() fires once all the hard-coded HTML is parsed and it's resources are fetched, typically coinciding with the removal of status-bar activity, unless lazy-load scripts are being used or some flash movie or something like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first chance you get to run Javascript is if you include it in the page outside any of the jQuery event callbacks. The further up the page it is, the sooner it will run (as it's parsed by the browser) so something like...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Running');
            //...
```

would execute as soon as the browser has read the first few lines from your server.

It's worth noting that there's usually very little point in running javascript that soon as there's nothing in the DOM for it to modify. That's why the `$(document).ready();` exists - to delay the script until there's a document to work with.

Comment: hmm.. I understood the question as he wants to *"wait until the "waiting for localhost" message in the browser goes away"* which would mean waiting until all resources that point to localhost are completely loaded, right?

Comment: @KevinB I either mis-read it or it's been edited. I believe you're right. The problem is that there's no direct correlation between when different browsers show status messages and document events fire.